# For loop not executing (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop

I am pretty new to typescript so I might be making an schoolboy error.
Anyway I have this code

```
const gCharData: any = {};
function buildChar()
{
    const key = "Char1";
    let currentChar = gCharData[key];
    if (!currentChar) {
        currentChar = {
            name: "Jack",
            parts: new Set(),
        };
        gCharData[key] = currentChar;
    }
    currentChar.parts.add("Head");
}
function foo(chars: { [x: string]: any; })
{
     for (var charName in chars) {
        const details = chars[charName];
    
        for (var name of details.parts) {
            /*NOT EXCUTING*/
        }
    }
}
function main()
{
    buildChar()
    foo(gCharData)
}
main();
```

And that second for loop is not executing.
Any Idea why ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should avoid using `any` in typescript as then it has no advantage over regular Javascript

Comment: `details.parts` is empty `Set: {} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is just with the `Set` object created, if you want to iterate over the parts `Set` object, one option is to do it this way:

```js
function foo(chars: { [x: string]: any; })
{
     for (var charName in chars) {
        const details = chars[charName];
    
        for (var name of Array.from(details.parts)) {
            console.log("value: " + name);
    }
}
```

Here is the code live: https://jsfiddle.net/0mkcpqnu/1/